# Opencart для новичка

Tags: веб-программирование, opencart

Постараюсь обьяснить пробему как можно детальнее. Я решил познакомиться с opencart.
Скачал архив опенкарт(3.0) из оффицального сайта.
Установил вроде все работает. Устанвил я в domains/mydomain/. После решил поменять тему(или шаблон не знаю как правильно)
Скачал опять же с оффицального сайта опенкарт архив бесплатной темы. Расспаковал прямь наверх как было в одном из тутариолов. Разрешил сливания папок и файлы с одинаковыми имена заменил.
там было еще из архива папка с именем themeinstall при входе в которую пишет что все установлено.
После зашел в админку settings/edit/ и там в theme я не нашел новый темы. Все тот же Default и кроме него ничего нету.

Comment: \catalog\view\theme\ - тут появилась папка новой темы?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin да появилось. Это видать какойта баг 3 версии. Скачал 2 версую и работает

Comment: может шаблон был под 2.x? 2 и 3 отличаются в файлах представления.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin  нет нет я помню что когда была 3 версия я из архива брал именна папку темы под 3

Comment: дело в том, что тема которая работает под 2.x  с большой вероятностью не сможет работать под 3.x. в 3.х используется twig, в 2.x - нет

Comment: @KirillKorushkin я уверен что с этим я справился). Я достал папку для нужной версии